# Doctrine ODM memory limit reached when inserting documents

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, memory, doctrine-orm

I have a little problem, I'm getting around 800 000 datas from a json and I'm trying to insert them into a MongoDB Database. But I reach memory limit (I've set it up to 8GB for testing) while doing this. I think my script isn't optimized but I can't find where. Can you guys help me ? Here is the script :

```
        $jsonResponse = json_decode($content->response);
        $datas = $jsonResponse->hits->hits;

        // On crée la collection si elle n'éxiste pas
        $collection = $connection->createCollection($table->getTableName(), false );

        // On enregistre les données dans la collection
        foreach ($datas as $data)
        {
            if(!empty($data) || $data)
            {
                $document['_id'] = $data->_id; // ID netwoof unique
                $document['_updated'] = substr($data->_source->_updated, 0, -3); // Date de dernière MàJ des données
                $document['_url'] = $data->_source->_url; // Start URL

                // On enregistre ensuite chaque champs définis dans le dashboard
                foreach ($fields as $field)
                {
                    // On récupère le nom du champs netwoof
                    $containerFieldName = $field->getContainerFieldName();

                    // On fait correspondre notre champ db avec celui netwoof
                    if( isset( $data->_source->$containerFieldName ) && (!empty($data->_source->$containerFieldName) || $data->_source->$containerFieldName == 0 ) )
                        $document[$field->getFieldName()] =  $data->_source->$containerFieldName;
                    /*else
                        $document[$field->getFieldName()] = null;*/

                }

                foreach ($customFields as $customField)
                {
                    if(!empty($customField->getFieldValue()))
                        $document[$customField->getFieldName()] = $customField->getFieldValue();
                }

                // Enregistrement des données
                $collection->save($document);
            }

            // On réinitialise la variable
            unset($document);
        }
```

Thanks all for your answer and sorry for my english.

Comment: you should try making big DB change by using cmd interface instead of PHP code, because PHP would break in between execution.

Comment: What do you mean ? because I can only get these datas by a REST API and using our GUI

Comment: Then probably PHP won't work with big DB operations, you need to apply some sort of logic like break big JSON file into chunks. Do DB operations in chunks etc.